# SLF4J Logger for Eclipse Juno with Mountain Lion

Tags: eclipse, macos, logging, slf4j

I've been running into trouble with slf4j logger system in Eclipse Juno. I'm pretty sure I have it included in my classpath and I've also included it inside of a Maven dependency, but I'm still running into issues. I've read similar issues with this problem but all of them seem to be outdated as they do not work in my instance of Eclipse. This is the error msg:

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I'm running this on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.1 with Java JDK 1.7.0_07 and Apache Maven 3.03. And again, I am using Eclipse Juno.

Comment: I don't see this error if I build from terminal (mvn package) but from within eclipse, I get the same error message.

Comment: Did you check the solution provided in my answer.? Did you manage to make it work.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse Juno and Indigo, when using the bundled maven version(m2e), are not suppressing the message SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". This behaviour is present from the m2e version 1.1.0.20120530-0009 and onwards.

Although, this is indicated as an error your logs will be saved normally. The highlighted error will still be present until there is a fix of this bug. More about this in the [m2e support site](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387064).

The current available solution is to use an external maven version rather than the bundled version of Eclipse. You can find about this solution and more details regarding this bug in the question below which is the exact same problem you are facing.

[SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)