# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". in a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I have a dependency for SLF4J. I am getting this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Here is my maven entry:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where is the problem?

---

**EDIT:**  Without log4j dependency I get the following exception

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:50)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr303.ApacheValidationProvider.createGenericConfiguration(ApacheValidationProvider.java:66)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:173)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:50)
    at com.daimler.zv9.basic.entity.AbstractEntity.<clinit>(AbstractEntity.java:73)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:228)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:195)
    at java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:168)
```

---

**EDIT2**: It is an example MAVEN Tree that I get

```
[INFO] com.myCompany.abc:ABC_Document:ejb:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.myCompany.abc:ABC_Basic:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.myCompany.iap:javax.j2ee:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.myCompany.iap:logging:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- com.myCompany.iap:util:jar:5.0.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.8.2:test
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
```

Comment: @Ceki Maybe you have an Idea?

Comment: is this a standalone program or deployed in some server?

Comment: @basiljames i get the error with mvn openjpa:sql command. it is not installed anywhere.

Comment: Have you added the log4j configuration file in classpath?

Comment: @basiljames Why do I need the properties?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16775/discussion-between-basiljames-and-kayser)

Comment: It looks like the version of slf4j-api that actually runs cannot find slf4j-log4j12 on its classpath. Are you sure that there isn't another slf4j-api.jar in your classpath?

Comment: @NicolaMusatti there are also Websphere 8 libraries but there is no slf4j-api.jar between them

Comment: With WAS 7 I remember solving similar problems by setting an option that reversed classpath traversal, putting application specific libraries first.

Comment: @Kayser My answer did not provide a solution to your problem.?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I am assuming you are using Eclipse as your developing environment.

Eclipse Juno, Indigo and Kepler when using the bundled maven version(m2e), are not suppressing the message SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". This behaviour is present from the m2e version 1.1.0.20120530-0009 and onwards.

Although, this is indicated as an error your logs will be saved normally. The highlighted error will still be present until there is a fix of this bug. More about this in the [m2e support site](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387064).

The current available solution is to use an external maven version rather than the bundled version of Eclipse. You can find about this solution and more details regarding this bug in the question below which i believe describes the same problem you are facing.

[SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

Comment: If the use of external maven version does not work, I advise to delete the content of your local Maven repository.

Comment: I had the same problem on Intellij IDEA and the same solution ("use an external maven version rather than the bundled version") works for me.

Answer (score 41):

Remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
```

`slf4j-log4j12` is the log4j binding for `slf4j` you dont need to add another log4j dependency.

**Added**
Provide the log4j configuration in `log4j.properties` and add it to your class path. There are sample configurations [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

or you can change your binding to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

if you are configuring slf4j due to some dependencies requiring it.

Comment: I removed it. I am getting this exception 'Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)'

Comment: One similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Comment: When slf4j-log4j is declared a dependency adding log4j as a dependency
is unnecessary but it should not hurt either. Moreover,
log4j.properties is irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: thanks worked for me

Comment: thanks! It helped me.

Comment: I was running selenium lib., tried to disable logs and nothing helped but then i come accross this and that really helped to fix the issue. Tnx for solution:-)

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this in IntelliJ and fixed it by adding the following to my pom:

```
<!-- logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Defined below -->
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: A better fix would be to use a `dependencyManagement` element which nails down the version for `slf4j-api`

Comment: I'm using spring boot 15. This solution worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The message you mention is quite clear:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

SLF4J API could not find a binding, and decided to default to a NOP implementation. In your case slf4j-log4j12.jar was somehow not visible when the LoggerFactory class was loaded into memory, which is admittedly *very* strange. What does "mvn dependency:tree" tell you?

The various dependency declarations may not even be directly at cause here. I strongly suspect that a pre-1.6 version of `slf4j-api.jar` is being deployed without your knowledge.

Comment: That is what dependency:tree tells: `[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:tree (default-cli) @ GEM_Web ---
[INFO] com.mycompany.proj:My_Web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ... 
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test`

Comment: The above is not very legible. IMO, it should be moved to the question part.