# SoapUI SLF4J: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder”

Tags: java, soapui, slf4j

How to resolve the problem of 'SLF4J: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder”' when running SoapUI (mine is 5.2.1) command-line testrunner.bat?

NOTE: This problem had been answered in a number of places for Maven, Eclipse, etc. but not for SoapUI. E.g.:

[SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". in a Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458469/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-in-a-maven-proj)

Answer (score 4):

The problem, as explained in http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html is that one (and only one) of the following is missing in the classpath: slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar.

I found that adding, e.g. slf4j-simple.jar to [SoapUI-Base]/bin/ext did not work, even though it apparently loaded it:

```
13:02:26,203 INFO  [SoapUI] Adding [C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\ext\slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar] to extensions classpath
13:02:26,983 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] initialized soapui-settings from [C:\Users\XXX\soapui-settings.xml]
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

What worked was to place slf4j-simple.jar, and more specifically, slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar (to be compatible with the SLF4J version used in SoapUI 5.2.1) into [SoapUI-Base]/lib.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

this is solution that help me.

1. I have downloaded last `slf4j` package from http://www.slf4j.org/download.html
2. Delete from `SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\lib` file `slf4j-api`
3. Insert to the `SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\lib` files from package `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-nop`

Now everything works fine.