# SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" in Kafka streams

Tags: maven, apache-kafka-streams

I get below error when I run a sample code like wordcount in Kafka Streams:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I visited the link: https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder
and tried adding one of the  slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar as mentioned in that link. but it didn't help.

I read that issue is with embedded maven version in eclipse but I tried creating project from console but still I ran into same issue.

- Kafka Streams version - 0.11.0.0
- Maven version - 3.3.9

is anyone aware of this issue? My next steps would be installing different maven version and try it.

Comment: This is a common maven/slf4j issue.  Have you looked at existing SO threads such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458469/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-in-a-maven-proj?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem running any of the Kafka streams examples from the maven produced jar. It appears to me to be a simple compile/test dependency issue. Running:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

the results show:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:1.0.0-cp1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
...
[INFO] +- io.confluent:common-utils:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:test
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:test
```

So the slf4j-log4j12 jar is only included in the test environment.
I added the following to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Rebuilding the jar and running with the appropriate log4j command line argument, the examples all now use logging. eg:

```
java -cp kafka-streams-examples-4.0.0-standalone.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties io.confluent.examples.streams.GlobalKTablesExample broker:9092 http://schema_registry:8081
```

Answer (score 0):

[slf4j-log4j12](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12) is now moved to [slf4j-reload4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-reload4j), you need add reload4j to your dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-reload4je</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

```
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-reload4j:2.0.11"
```

See also: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_320_notable

> Kafka has replaced log4j with reload4j due to security concerns. This only affects modules that specify a logging backend (connect-runtime and kafka-tools are two such examples). A number of modules, including kafka-clients, leave it to the application to specify the logging backend. More information can be found at reload4j. Projects that depend on the affected modules from the Kafka project should use slf4j-log4j12 version 1.7.35 or above or slf4j-reload4j to avoid possible compatibility issues originating from the logging framework.