# Adding javax.servlet-api dependency throws exception that org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder faild to load but i don't use sl4j, i use thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, thymeleaf

Basicaly title. I'm trying to run simple spring5 + thymeleaf project. If i don't add servlet-api i get an error that

```
cannot access javax.servlet.ServletException
```

But if i add servlet-api, project starts and works fine , but i get an error on startup:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

But i don't use sl4j, i use thymeleaf. How does servlet exception connected with sl4j and how should i manage it?

**UPD**

I understand that my question is wrong. But i need help with connected problem:
As someone suggested i added

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But i still get Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". exception. Any ideas?

**UPD**

as someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13268356/8367625) this is a bug of ide

Comment: Add these three jars  `slf4j-api-1.6.6,slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6  and log4j-1.2.17`

Comment: Are you using pom file or similar? Please post it if you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using IntelIj idea.
As someone sugested i added log4j and sl4j dependencies becouse servlet-api uses loging by default. And my exception that class is failed to load is just a bug of ide as it was mentioned in another question and everything including logging works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add slf4j.jar in your dependency or your project. Spring internally use slf4j for its own logging.