# Eclipse - Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SLF4J: Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

I am using **eclipse juno** to run someone's else Java code using **maven**(m2eclipse plugin). But I am getting following message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

On the [official website](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html), I found the following fix for this problem:

```
This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. 
This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. 
Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.
```

So I copied slf4j-simple.jar in **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib"**. But I am still getting error.

Please guide me what is correct solution. I am a Java newbie.

Also can someone please mention what exactly should be the value for `JAVA_HOME`, `CLASSPATH` and `CLASS` variables. I am confused whether it should be path of `jre` or `jdk` or any?

**UPDATE:**

Following dependency for `slf4j` are there in project `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.6</version>
           <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I have updated my project. Also the `slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar` and `slf4j-simple-1.5.6.jar` are showing up in **"Maven dependencies"** in my project. And `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.class` is also present in `slf4j-simple-1.5.6.jar`

Comment: what happens during mvn clean install?

Comment: just add one dependency into POM.xml:

<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>    
    </dependency>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Eclipse Juno, Indigo and Kepler when using the bundled maven version(m2e), are not suppressing the message SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". This behaviour is present from the m2e version 1.1.0.20120530-0009 and onwards.

Although, this is indicated as an error your logs will be saved normally. The highlighted error will still be present until there is a fix of this bug. More about this in the [m2e support site](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387064).

The current available solution is to use an external maven version rather than the bundled version of Eclipse. You can find about this solution and more details regarding this bug in the question below which i believe describes the same problem you are facing.

[SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error)

Answer (score 12):

Did you update the project (right-click on the project, "Maven" > "Update project...")? Otherwise, you need to check if `pom.xml` contains the necessary slf4j dependencies, e.g.:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with details of `pom.xml` content. Please have a look.

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: by clicking Run As->Maven Build

Answer (score 2):

After placing the jar file in desired location, you need to add the jar file by **right click** on

> Project --> properties --> Java Build Path --> Libraries --> Add Jar.

Comment: I have also added it manually, but still same error