# Spark Java 500 Internal Server error, Exceptions are not stack traced in console

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, freemarker, spark-java

My Pom.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mongodb.week1</groupId>
    <artifactId>m101j-week1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SPARK DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-template-freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.25-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build> 

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my template file `hello.ftl` is as below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello ${hello}</h1>
</body>
```

And my `SparkRoutes.java` looks as below,

```
package com.mongodb.week1.lesson13;

import spark.ModelAndView;
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.template.freemarker.FreeMarkerEngine;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static spark.Spark.get;

 public class SparkRoutes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/", (Request req, Response res) -> {
            Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
            attributes.put("hello", "Hello World spark freemarker !");
            return new ModelAndView(attributes, "hello.ftl");
        }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
    }


}
```

IDE used : Intellij Community 2016.3.3
JDK used : Java 8

`500 internal server error` is shown in browser when following uri is called `http://localhost:4567/`

Intellij console Stack Traces are empty except the following messages,

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/Documents/balajichander/MONGODB/WEEK 1/intellij workspace/target/classes:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.1/mongo-java-driver-3.4.1.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/com/sparkjava/spark-core/2.2/spark-core-2.2.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-server-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-http-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-util-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-io-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-webapp/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-webapp-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-xml/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-xml-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlet/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-servlet-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-security/9.0.2.v20130417/jetty-security-9.0.2.v20130417.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/com/sparkjava/spark-template-freemarker/2.3/spark-template-freemarker-2.3.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.25-incubating/freemarker-2.3.25-incubating.jar:/Users/muthuselvam/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13/slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.mongodb.week1.lesson13.SparkRoutes
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Process finished with exit code 100
```

1. How to enable stack traces in `spark java`
2. How to run spark project with free marker templates properly

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It appears that there may be other questions on the site that already address this issue.  For this error message `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".`.  Please check these other questions out first.  If you still can't find the answer, please point out what is different between your question and the ones I linked:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473953/eclipse-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error

Comment: I have tihs exact same issue.