# slf4j & log4j2 maven setup query

Tags: java, maven, logging, slf4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 and slf4j in my project & using maven for the build.  I am using the following pom file (releveant dependencies shown only) but I am getting the error copied below with this pom file - any idea what I need to add/remove to get this to work.  I have already visited the url in the error as well as the log4j2 dependencies page so please do not just point to URLs in your response.

**Message:**

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

**pom file**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
</properties>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
        <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version> 
     </dependency>
```

**Update:**
I added the following dependency to my pom file and I see the jar in my mavenrepository - though I still see the same message when I run mvn clean/install

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You seem to be missing the following from your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The groupId should be "org.apache.logging.log4j" and the version "2.0.1", as described here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

Comment: my mistake - yes, the version should be 2.0.1 not the beta one and not with the adapters group id

Comment: @user3813256 then why did you mark the answer correct if it did not solve the issue?

Answer (score 10):

Your log4j2 configuration in correct (POM side), but you never say to slf4j where it should write (backend part).

Your should add that to your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It is the Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding. According to [Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/) *The Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding allows applications coded to the SLF4J API to use Log4j 2 as the implementation*

If it still does not work, you may have an Eclipse problem because Eclipse m2e is known to be weird regarding slf4j. According to this detailed post from SO [SLF4J: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder”. error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error) a workaround could be to use an external maven to do the build.

Comment: I still see the same message when I run maven clean/install via eclipse.  I seem to have all the dependencies in my maven repo - slf4j=api-1.7.7, log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.1, log4j-api-2.0.1, log4j-core-2.0.1 but I get the message when I run maven and my log file output does not get generated.  I get the file output with the same log4j2 xml file when I do not use maven but have all the jars in my lib directory and use eclipse for the build path

Comment: @user3813256: I hoped it would be enough because I do not use Eclipse, but I've updated my answer with references to another post.

Comment: I'll accept as soon as I can verify - I think you are right but I need to prove it on my computer - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the log4j-slf4j-impl dependency, you also need the slf4j-ext dependency.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/dependencies.html

Comment: Last column says Optional = YES.

Answer (score -1):

I think your first pom.xml is correct, (dependency is correct), maybe config file location is wrong

**pom.xml**

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
```