# Using log4j2 with slf4j: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

So I have tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386651/slf4j-log4j2-maven-setup-query) (non-maven implementation) and requirements in their [web site](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) for adding slf4j to log4j. and tried using this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
        logger.info("test");
    }
```

and added the following to my library

- log4j-api-2.3.jar
- log4j-core-2.3.jar
- log4j-sl4j-impl-2.3.jar
- log4j-to-sl4j-2.3.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar

when I try running it I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.containsKey(ConcurrentHashMap.java:964)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:40)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.newLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:284)...
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: You can see https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings how to exclude log4j :-)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You're creating a call-loop with `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.3.jar` and `log4j-to-slf4j-2.3.jar`.

`log4j-slf4j-impl-2.3.jar` is the implementation of the adapter that sends slf4j calls to log4j.

`log4j-to-slf4j-2.3.jar` is sending log4j calls right back to slf4j. *Remove this one*.

Comment: You can remove the log4j-to-sl4j in Gradle:    configurations {
  all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
 }

Comment: my case is removing the upper one, guess either is okay.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, if you have **logback** in your classpath, it must be removed as well!

Answer (score 1):

Idea 1:

The above answer works. Mine was a multi module project and the `log4j-to-slf4j-2.3.jar` dependency was being by pulled by a different project. I had to scan each project to figure which project was pulling in this. I used the following command to do at a project level.

```
gradlew common:dependencies --configuration runtime
```

`common` is the name of the project
`configuration runtime` - you can change this to suit your need

---

Idea 2:

If you are using spring which has multi module projects. Then you can simply add the following config in every subproject's `build.gradle` or `dependency.gradle`

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone's search for `java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14` led to this question.

The root cause is already explained in Andreas's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32366618/1113392).

In my case it was the mockserver dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockserver-netty-no-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>5.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Which had the classes from slf4j/jul bundled inside it, which resulted in the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:167)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:979)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.innerNormalizedLoggingCallHandler(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:156)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:172)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:979)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.innerNormalizedLoggingCallHandler(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:156)
    at org.slf4j.jul.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(JDK14LoggerAdapter.java:172)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
```

As the those classes were not inside a transitive dependency an exclusion was not possible. So the solution was just to replace the mentioned dependency with all denepndies required to run mockserver, again in my case

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
   <version>5.15.0</version>
</dependency>
```