Test cases failing after upgrading spring-boot-parameter-store-integration dependency
Integration test cases have been failing after upgrading the spring-boot-parameter-store-integration dependency to 2.0.0. and software.amazon.awssdk:bom to 2.26.15.
Spring boot version that I am using is 3.3.1
classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.3.1")

I am getting below errors:
GcsLogAspectWeavingTest > invokeAnnotatedMethod_WorkflowStepMonitorListener() FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at SpringApplication.java:825
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:119
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at SpringApplication.java:825

        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:119

Below is the code for GcsLogAspectWeavingTest
package com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.logging

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*
import com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.message.SQSTextMessage
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.service.LoadToCheetahActivityInputProcessor
import com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.queue.WorkflowStepMonitorListener
import com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.service.amazonaws.stepfunction.StepFunctionClientWrapper
import com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.service.ssm.SystemsManagerConfig
import com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.service.ssm.SystemsManagerService
import com.tr.gcs.delivertocheetah.service.util.RetryUtil
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.SpyBean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedPrivateField")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension)
@Import(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator)
@SpringBootTest(classes = [WorkflowStepMonitorListener, GcsLogAspect])
class GcsLogAspectWeavingTest
{
    @Mock
    private SQSTextMessage sqsTextMessage

    @MockBean
    private StepFunctionClientWrapper stepFunctionClientWrapper

    @MockBean
    private LoadToCheetahActivityInputProcessor loadToCheetahActivityInputProcessor

    @MockBean
    private SystemsManagerService systemsManagerService

    @MockBean
    private SystemsManagerConfig systemsManagerConfig

    @MockBean
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper

    @MockBean
    private RetryUtil retryUtil

    @Autowired
    private WorkflowStepMonitorListener workflowStepMonitorListener

    @SpyBean
    private GcsLogAspect gcsLogAspect

    @Test
    void invokeAnnotatedMethod_WorkflowStepMonitorListener()
    {
        workflowStepMonitorListener.onMessage(sqsTextMessage)

        verify(gcsLogAspect).populateThreadContext(any())
    }
}


It's due to some version incompatibility issue. Any idea as to how I can resolve the error ?
Added my build.gradle file as well:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://tr1.jfrog.io/tr1/libs-release/"
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER")
                password System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN")
            }
        }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.1.8")
    }
}

apply {
    plugin 'groovy'
    plugin 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    plugin 'codenarc'
    plugin 'org.springframework.boot'
}

//Upgrading log4j2 version to 2.19.0
ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.19.0'

def artifactoryUser = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_USER")
def artifactoryToken = System.getenv("ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN")
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://tr1.jfrog.io/tr1/libs-release/"
        credentials {
            username artifactoryUser
            password artifactoryToken
        }
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366586/using-log4j2-with-slf4j
    all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    all*.exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
    all*.exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: '*'

    qedTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    qedTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
    intTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    intTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.20.15'
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Groovy
    implementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.15'

    //Spring Boot
    implementation(
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.19',
            'org.springframework:spring-expression:6.0.8',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security',
            'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache',
            'org.springframework:spring-context-support',
            'org.springframework:spring-jms',
            'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0',
            'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:2.0.0'
    )

    // TR
    implementation(
            'com.tr.cars:cars-logging-java:2.1.1',
            'com.tr.cars:cars-http-client-java:1.11.0',
            'com.tr.cars:cars-aws-clients-java:1.15.0',
            'io.netty:netty-codec-http2:4.1.108.Final',
            'com.tr.gcs:gcs-http-logging-log4j2:17.0.1',
            'com.tr.gcs:control-plane-client-java:0.2.1-RELEASE',
            'com.tr.gcs:gcs-authorization:18.1.0-RELEASE',
            'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
    )

    // External
    implementation(
            'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0',
            'com.squareup.okio:okio:3.4.0',
            'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:3.1.4',
            'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0',
            'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2',
            // JMS
            'com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client:9.3.5.0',
            'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.78',
            //AWS
            'software.amazon.awssdk:s3',
            'software.amazon.awssdk:sts',
            'software.amazon.awssdk:sqs',
            'software.amazon.awssdk:ssm',
            'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-stepfunctions:1.12.705',
            'com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib:2.1.0',
            //jsch enabling sftp access
            'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55',
            //Logging with Log4j2
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2',
            'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api',
            // https://github.com/coveo/spring-boot-parameter-store-integration
            'com.coveo:spring-boot-parameter-store-integration:2.0.0',
            'org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.8',
            'org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.8',
            'org.springframework:spring-context:6.0.8'
    )

    //Swagger
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi:2.1.0")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0")
    implementation('org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0')

    //Aspose
//    compile(group: 'com.tr.contentworkflowservice.aspose', name: 'aspose-words', version: '20.6', classifier: 'jdk17')
//    implementation(group: 'com.tr.contentworkflowservice.aspose', name: 'aspose-words', version: '20.6', classifier: 'jdk17')
//    implementation('com.aspose:aspose-pdf:19.7')

    //Tests
    testImplementation(
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test',
            'net.minidev:json-smart:2.4.9',
            'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.12.0',
            'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:5.12.0',
            'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.14.0',
            'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.14.0',
            'org.objenesis:objenesis:3.3',
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2',
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.9.2',
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2',
            'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.24.2',
            'xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2',
            'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.4',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.14',
            'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.14',
            'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ssm:1.12.418',
            'org.awaitility:awaitility-groovy:4.2.0',
            'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:5.3.0',
            'io.rest-assured:rest-assured-all:5.3.0',
            'org.testcontainers:localstack:1.17.6',
            'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.17.6',
            'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.27.2',
            'io.github.artsok:rerunner-jupiter:2.1.6'
    )
    testRuntimeOnly(
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.9.2'
    )
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

codenarc {
    toolVersion = "3.2.0-groovy-4.0"
}

codenarcMain {
    dependsOn(compileJava, compileGroovy)
    ignoreFailures false
    configFile file('codenarc/codenarc-main.rules')
    reports {
        text {
            enabled = true
        }
    }

    finalizedBy {
        writeCodenarcMainFailures
    }
}

sourceSets {
    qedTest {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/qed/groovy']
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/qed/resources')
    }

    intTest {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/integration-test/groovy']
            compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
            runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/resources', 'src/integration-test/resources']
        }
    }
}

task writeCodenarcMainFailures {
    doLast {
        println "****************************** CODE NARC MAIN ******************************"
        File codeNarcFile = file("build/reports/codenarc/main.txt")
        if (codeNarcFile.exists())
        {
            println codeNarcFile.getText()
        }
        else
        {
            println "No codenarc violations found in main code"
        }
        println "****************************** CODE NARC MAIN ******************************"
    }
}

codenarcTest {
    dependsOn(compileTestJava, compileTestGroovy)
    ignoreFailures false
    configFile file('codenarc/codenarc-test.rules')
    reports {
        text {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
    finalizedBy {
        writeCodenarcTestFailures
    }
}

codenarcIntTest {
    dependsOn(compileTestJava, compileTestGroovy)
    ignoreFailures false
    configFile file('codenarc/codenarc-test.rules')
    reports {
        text {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
    finalizedBy {
        writeCodenarcIntTestFailures
    }
}

task writeCodenarcIntTestFailures {
    doLast {
        println "****************************** CODE NARC TEST ******************************"
        File codeNarcFile = file("build/reports/codenarc/intTest.txt")
        if (codeNarcFile.exists())
        {
            println codeNarcFile.getText()
        }
        else
        {
            println "No codenarc violations found in integration test code"
        }
        println "****************************** CODE NARC TEST ******************************"
    }
}

task writeCodenarcTestFailures {
    doLast {
        println "****************************** CODE NARC TEST ******************************"
        File codeNarcFile = file("build/reports/codenarc/test.txt")
        if (codeNarcFile.exists())
        {
            println codeNarcFile.getText()
        }
        else
        {
            println "No codenarc violations found in test code"
        }
        println "****************************** CODE NARC TEST ******************************"
    }
}

codenarcQedTest {
    dependsOn(compileQedTestJava, compileQedTestGroovy)
    ignoreFailures false
    configFile file('codenarc/codenarc-qed.rules')
    reports {
        text {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
    finalizedBy {
        writeCodenarcQedTestFailures
    }
}

task writeCodenarcQedTestFailures {
    doLast {
        println "****************************** CODE NARC QED TEST ******************************"
        File codeNarcFile = file("build/reports/codenarc/qedTest.txt")
        if (codeNarcFile.exists())
        {
            println codeNarcFile.getText()
        }
        else
        {
            println "No codenarc violations found in qed test code"
        }
        println "****************************** CODE NARC QED TEST ******************************"
    }
}

task qedTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    testClassesDirs = project.sourceSets.qedTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.qedTest.runtimeClasspath
    testReportDirName = 'qedTest'
    reports.html.enabled = true
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams true
        events "failed"
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true
    }
    //turn on after multiple features testing is finished
    //maxParallelForks(8)
    finalizedBy {
        codenarcQedTest
    }
}

task qedTestJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title' : 'Qed Test App',
                'Implementation-Version': bootJar.version
    }
    classifier = 'qedTests'
    from sourceSets.qedTest.output.classesDirs
    from sourceSets.qedTest.resources
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'
    testLogging {
        showExceptions = true
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
        events = ['failed']
    }
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.intTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.intTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest

This is my Spring

need more detail, such as which method is missing

Hi @leaf_soba
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:119
StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java is the missing method.

StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java is a class, I need the missing "method" to troubleshoot your NoSuchMethodError. For example, customizeEvaluationContext is a method in StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java

I added some more dependencies and now it's giving this error:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.ClientOverrideConfiguration$Builder software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.ClientOverrideConfiguration$Builder.retryStrategy(java.util.function.Consumer)'

Seems like retryStrategy method is missing.

please post the code in SpringApplication.java line 825

hi @leaf_soba, I updated the answer with my final build.gradle file. A test case is failing with below exception ( I am not facing the above mentioned exception now ):

@leaf_soba please refer to this new exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at SpringApplication.java:809
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at ParameterStorePropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:37
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:641
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at SpringApplication.java:809

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
