# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment)

Tags: spring, maven, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j2.xml instad of log4j but I keep getting

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

File is located under src/main/resources

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="WIP">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %MDC{threadTrackId} %40c{1.} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="warn">
        <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="com.test" level="debug"/>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="info"/>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am not sure if the file is being located correctly but the appenders inside it are not read correctly or the file is not being located.

in My pom file I have the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my build section in pom

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.wirecard.wip.db.RecreateDatabase</mainClass>
                <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In my class this is how I initialize my logger

```
private static final Logger LOG =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

and my imports are

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

I run my class through maven using this command

```
mvn -B -f pom.xml exec:java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml
```

I also tried

```
mvn -B -f pom.xml exec:java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2.xml
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to use just log4j2.xml with the actually old log4j libs? You might be setting up libs dependencies incorreclty. Check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386651/slf4j-log4j2-maven-setup-query

Comment: @AlexeyR. I already tried this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The message

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

is coming from log4j1. You must still have the jar on your classpath. Run "mvn dependency:tree" and see what is bringing it in and then add an exclude for it.

Comment: yes actually that was the problem , I figured it out several days ago abut forgot to post an answer , thanks for your help

Comment: i also faced same problem, i had a jar that pointed to log4j1 in my classpath. I traced that jar and found that it was indirectly coming from another jar. Excluded that inner jar and built once again. Now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer log4j.properties file from custom location, create log file also at custom location and if you are using:

1. spring boot
2. log4j version 1.2+

and you exclude the

> "spring-boot-starter-logging"

from

> "spring-boot-starter"

Then add this dependency after this above dependency in maven

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do the clean build.

It will refer the file from custom location and create log file as well.
Hope this will help someone.