# Spring Tool Suite error when running as java app

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring Boot using STS and following a tutorial on Udemy. I'm getting the following error when trying to run the app as a java application. I have looked at other similar posts and nothing seems to be new. Most of the questions are from 3-5 years ago. I have attempted putting some dependencies in my pom but it gave me more errors than I began with so i removed them.

The error is:
Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.in28minutes.springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>first-springboot-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Here is what i was trying to run:

```
package com.in28minutes.springboot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, 
    args);

    }

}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to what I can do to fix this? Do I bind? The original example code can be found here at the instructor's repo: https://github.com/in28minutes/SpringBootForBeginners/blob/master/Step01.md

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: It needs to run as an spring boot application. Not a java application. The spring container does a lot of stuff specific to it.

Comment: I thought maybe the instructor misspoke in the video so I tried that. I get the same error if I try to run it as a spring boot application.

Comment: check ~/.m2 folder to make sure it is there

Comment: @efekctive I appreciate your patience. I'm still new to all of this (maven,spring etc...). I went to my .m2 folder and drilled down on the slf4j folder and i see the following: jcl-over-slf4j , slf4j-api , slf4j-parent , jul-to-slf4j , slf4j-jdk14 , slf4j-simple , log4j-over-slf4j , slf4j-log4j12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not use STS but following from this [docs](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4) you should run your app as **Spring Boot App** since you're using Spring Boot.
But your error it's seems because dependency error, if you familiar with *command line* I suggest you to perform `mvn clean install` before run your Spring project to make sure all the dependency is downloaded.

Another tips, if you're good with *command line* try to execute `mvn spring-boot:run` on your project directory and it will execute your Spring project.