# Logback not working with Spring Boot and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok, logback-classic

I am trying to set up a Spring Boot application on a Tomcat server, but I am running into issues. I keep getting the following error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

Here is the main class of my program:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataPowerSyncProcess extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
        return application.sources(DataPowerSyncProcess.class);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        addCommonProperties(new SpringApplicationBuilder())
                .build().run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder addCommonProperties(SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder){
        return applicationBuilder.sources(DataPowerSyncProcess.class);
    }
}
```

What I have been noticing is that it seems the through the error I stated before happens after this line in the class SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
WebApplicationContext rootAppContext = this.createRootApplicationContext(servletContext);
```

Edit: here is my POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.project.listener_loadplanning_datapowersyncprocess</groupId>
  <artifactId>listener_loadplanning_datapowersyncprocess</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A Camel Spring Route</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring-boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Camel BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Dalston.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Camel -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JBHunt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jbhunt</groupId>
      <artifactId>lib_SecurePIDReader</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.16.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you searched? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916706/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder-error

Comment: Could you also please add your pom.xml please ? It's probably a dependency problem and it might be due to two separate libraries using different logs appender (log4j-simple and log4j-api for example) which would lead to further problem on application boot/

Comment: Mhradek I had not, but a lot of the solutions in it, look like things I have tried from other posts.I have added the POM file now for better clarification